# Cross Origin Opener Policy would block the window closed call error when attempting to authenticate with google

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML file that is intended to display google maps using the google maps API, and put a layer on top of it using the google earth engine API. This is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key="></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/earthengine/0.1.365/earthengine-api.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        /* Set the size of the div element that contains the map. */
        #map-container {
            height: 400px;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #eee;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- The "Sign in with Google" button, initially hidden. -->
    <input id="g-sign-in" type="image"
        src="https://developers.google.com/identity/images/btn_google_signin_light_normal_web.png"
        onclick="onSignInButtonClick()" alt="Sign in with Google" />

    <!-- Element where map will be added. -->
    <div id="map-container"></div>
    <script>
        // The OAuth Client ID from the Google Developers Console.
        const CLIENT_ID = "";

        // Initializes Maps JavaScript API and Earth Engine API, instructing the map
        // to pull tiles from Earth Engine and to overlay them on the map.
        function setUpMap() {
            // Initialize the Earth Engine API. Must be called once before using the API.
            ee.initialize();

            // Get a reference to the placeholder DOM element to contain the map.
            const mapContainerEl = document.getElementById("map-container");

            // Create an interactive map inside the placeholder DOM element.
            const embeddedMap = new google.maps.Map(mapContainerEl, {
                // Pan and zoom initial map viewport to Grand Canyon.
                center: { lng: -112.8598, lat: 36.2841 },
                zoom: 9,
            });

            // Use the Earth Engine script URL to load the script into the map.
            var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S5P/OFFL/L3_SO2')
                .select('SO2_column_number_density')
                .filterDate('2023-12-01', '2024-01-01');

            var band_viz = {
                min: 0.0,
                max: 0.0015,
                palette: ['black', 'blue', 'purple', 'cyan', 'green', 'yellow', 'red']
            };

            Map.addLayer(collection.mean(), band_viz, 'Sulfur Dioxide', true, 0.5);
            Map.setCenter(0.0, 0.0, 2);

            print(collection)

        }

        // Handles clicks on the sign-in button.
        function onSignInButtonClick() {
            // Display popup allowing the user to sign in with their Google account and to
            // grant appropriate permissions to the app.
            ee.data.authenticateViaPopup(setUpMap);
        }

        // If the user is signed in, display a popup requesting permissions needed to
        // run the app, otherwise show the sign-in button.
        ee.data.authenticateViaOauth(
            // The OAuth Client ID defined above.
            CLIENT_ID,
            // Callback invoked immediately when user is already signed in.
            setUpMap,
            // Show authentication errors in a popup.
            alert,
            // Request permission to only read and compute Earth Engine data on behalf of
            // user.
            ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/earthengine.readonly'],
            // Show sign-in button if reusing existing credentials fails.
            () => document.getElementById("g-sign-in").removeAttribute("hidden"),
            // Don't require ability to write and access Cloud Platform on behalf of the
            // user.
            true
        );
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

When attempting to run this I can click the button for signing in and I can sign in as expected, but nothing shows up, I just get a blank white screen, and when opening the console to inspect I get this error "Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy policy would block the window.closed call."
I made sure to add the necessary Authorized Javascript Origins and the Authorized Redirect URI on my project in console.cloud.google.com. Any ideas what could be the issue here? Considering my code is basically a copy paste of this: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/custom-apps/client-js which is the official google documentation for how to work with Earth Engine API in Client-Side Web Apps